# Wrong behavior after update to v63 (Chrome) in Cursor auto

Tags: css, google-chrome

Yesterday (and today 12/18/2017) i updated my chrome browser to "Version **63.0.3239.108** (Official Build) (64-bit)" and something i found accidentally was about `cursor` issue in this version. I was added `cursor: auto` to some elements in my CSS and it was as i expected (totally normal) but now, after the update, `cursor` on those elements will not behave like they should be or at least like it used to. (In before, for `a` elements `cursor` was `pointer` and for plain texts was `text`, ofc after applying `cursor: auto` to them).

Based on *Mozila MDN*, initial value for `cursor` is `auto` same as W3 mentioned in their docs, but my chrome dev has no `auto` value for `cursor` and also act totally different from this description:

> auto: The browser will determine the cursor to display based on the context. E.g., equivalent to text when hovering text.

The question is are google dev changed the behavior of `cursor: auto` or deprecated/removed it from their engine, or this is sort of a bug? If they mentioned `cursor: auto` as deprecate property please link me to it because i couldn't find anything related to this problem in their "changelog" and forum.

This is a fiddle that represent the issue: [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6vaxd7e9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `auto` value for **[cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)** is determined by the context:

> The browser will determine the cursor to display based on the context. E.g., equivalent to `text` when hovering text.

And the `text` value states that:

> The text can be selected. Typically the shape of an I-beam.

Essentially, because you can **select** the text in a hyperlink, the browser determines the `I-beam` to be the most appropriate cursor. This is not specific to Chrome's latest version (I just tested this in `63.0.3239.84`), nor is it specific even to Chrome, as other browsers also exhibit this behaviour.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: So its mean always it was in this way? You are not able to test it in older chrome versions? If it was always like this, i wonder how before the update i was witness different behavior (i didn't change anything in my project)? And i am not sure about this "because you can select the text in a hyperlink, the browser determines the `I-beam`" you have any references? Thanks for your time +1

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it's always been this way; I just confirmed that this is indeed the behaviour in both Firefox and IE. With regard to the browser determination, I **assume** that it takes the highest possible valid option from [**this list**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor#Formal_syntax) (just like you would override CSS values). `text` comes later than `cursor`, so I guess it takes higher priority. You can always manually specify what the `cursor` should be if it's really necessary though :)